# SQL query in PHP to search 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP Code:

```
$sql="SELECT
    DISTINCT customer.*, 
    customer.sequence, 
    customer.accountnumber, 
    customer.resellerid, 
    customer.voip_account, 
    customer.company, 
    customer.company_status, 
    customer.title, 
    customer.forename, 
    customer.surname, 
    customer.email, 
    customer.phone 

    FROM customer, contacts, customer_phonelines WHERE 

    customer.sequence = contacts.company ";

    if($_GET["type"] != '') {
        $sql.="AND customer.company_status = '".$_GET["type"]."' ";
    } else {
        $sql.="AND customer.company_status = 'Customer' ";
    }

    if($_GET["search"] != '') {
        $sql.="AND ";
        $sql.="(customer_phonelines.phone_number LIKE '%".$search."%'  OR customer.company LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        CONCAT_WS(' ',customer.forename, customer.surname) LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        CONCAT_WS(' ',customer.second_forename, customer.second_surname) LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        CONCAT_WS(' ',customer.third_forename, customer.third_surname) LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        customer.email LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        customer.phone LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        customer.address1 LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        customer.address2 LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        customer.postcode LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 

        CONCAT_WS(' ',contacts.forename, contacts.surname) LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        contacts.email LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        contacts.phone LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        contacts.mobile LIKE '%".$search."%' )";

        //$sql.="AND customer.sequence = customer_phonelines.client_seq ";
    }
    $sql.="ORDER BY customer.company ASC ";
```

which runs my SQL Query fine

however, if there is no row in `customer_phonelines` for the returned row in `customer` it returns no rows at all.

i want to be able to return rows if there is no row in `customer_phonelines` that relates to `customer.sequence`

UPDATED:

`$sql="SELECT

```
customer.sequence, 
customer.accountnumber, 
customer.resellerid, 
customer.voip_account, 
customer.company, 
customer.company_status, 
customer.title, 
customer.forename, 
customer.surname, 
customer.email, 
customer.phone 

FROM customer, contacts, customer_phonelines WHERE 

customer.sequence = contacts.company ";

if($_GET["type"] != '') {
    $sql.="AND customer.company_status = '".$_GET["type"]."' ";
} else {
    $sql.="AND customer.company_status = 'Customer' ";
}

if($_GET["search"] != '') {
    $sql.="AND ";
    $sql.="(customer_phonelines.phone_number LIKE '%".$search."%'  OR customer.company LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
    CONCAT_WS(' ',customer.forename, customer.surname) LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
    CONCAT_WS(' ',customer.second_forename, customer.second_surname) LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
    CONCAT_WS(' ',customer.third_forename, customer.third_surname) LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
    customer.email LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
    customer.phone LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
    customer.address1 LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
    customer.address2 LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
    customer.postcode LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 

    CONCAT_WS(' ',contacts.forename, contacts.surname) LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
    contacts.email LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
    contacts.phone LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
    contacts.mobile LIKE '%".$search."%' )";

    $sql.="AND customer.sequence = customer_phonelines.client_seq ";
}
$sql.="group by customer.sequence ORDER BY customer.company ASC ";`
```

when running this query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT cu.* 
           FROM customer cu
           JOIN contacts co
             ON co.company = cu.sequence 
           JOIN customer_phonelines p
             ON p.client_seq = cu.sequence 
          WHERE cu.company_status = '$_GET[type]'
            AND 
              ( p.phone_number LIKE '%$search%'
             OR cu.company LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR CONCAT_WS(' ',cu.forename, cu.surname) LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR CONCAT_WS(' ',cu.second_forename, cu.second_surname) LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR CONCAT_WS(' ',cu.third_forename, cu.third_surname) LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR cu.email LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR cu.phone LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR cu.address1 LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR cu.address2 LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR cu.postcode LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR CONCAT_WS(' ',co.forename, co.surname) LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR co.email LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR co.phone LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR co.mobile LIKE '%$search%'
              )
          ORDER 
             BY cu.company ASC;

this is the `$sql` output:

SELECT DISTINCT cu.* 
           FROM customer cu 
           JOIN contacts co 
             ON co.company = cu.sequence 
           JOIN customer_phonelines p 
             ON p.client_seq = cu.sequence 
          WHERE cu.company_status = 'Customer' 
            AND 
              ( p.phone_number LIKE '%green%' 
             OR cu.company LIKE '%green%' 
             OR CONCAT_WS(' ',cu.forename, cu.surname) LIKE '%green%' 
             OR CONCAT_WS(' ',cu.second_forename, cu.second_surname) LIKE '%green%' 
             OR CONCAT_WS(' ',cu.third_forename, cu.third_surname) LIKE '%green%' 
             OR cu.email LIKE '%green%' 
             OR cu.phone LIKE '%green%' 
             OR cu.address1 LIKE '%green%' 
             OR cu.address2 LIKE '%green%' 
             OR cu.postcode LIKE '%green%' 
             OR CONCAT_WS(' ',co.forename, co.surname) LIKE '%green%' 
             OR co.email LIKE '%green%' 
             OR co.phone LIKE '%green%' 
             OR co.mobile LIKE '%green%' 
              ) 
          ORDER 
             BY cu.company ASC;
```

Comment: Use `OUTER JOIN + ON`'s for each table where the data may be `NULL`. Right now your query is using `INNER JOIN`'s (by default).

Comment: Can u try GroupBy instant of DISTINCT

Comment: And that's (partly) why we stopped using comma joins in 1992.

Comment: @KarthikKeyan that still doesn't show any rows if they have no record in `customer_phonelines` i added my new code to question

Comment: Also, why are you selecting the same information twice?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Of course, if the op is going to use a LEFT JOIN then they might as well dispense with that JOIN altogether, because they select no columns from those tables.

Comment: @Strawberry what information?

Comment: @Strawberry true dat. I should've seen that but in my lack-of-coffee-induced-haze I missed it.

Comment: @charlie All the columns in the customer table (well, all the ones that we know about anyway).

Comment: @JayBlanchard Gotta fix that buddy. We need your 'a' game ;-)

Comment: Just poured a large cup @Strawberry, 'a' game of some sort is coming up!

Comment: whats wrong with selecting that information? should i just use `select *`

Comment: `my_table.*` is (evil) shorthand for 'all the columns in `my_table`'. So, there's no point in then naming each individual column (although best practice is to do the exact opposite - so don't use `my_table.*` and instead specifically name each column: `mytable.col1,my_table.col2,etc...`

Comment: thats what i had done but you asked why i selected all information twice?

Comment: No. You did both. `DISTINCT customer.*, customer.sequence, customer.accountnumber, etc.`

Answer (score 1):

Charlie, just FYI, one permutation of your query is functionally identical to the following...

```
SELECT DISTINCT cu.* 
           FROM customer cu
           JOIN contacts co
             ON co.company = cu.sequence 
           JOIN customer_phonelines p
             ON p.client_seq = cu.sequence 
          WHERE cu.company_status = '$_GET[type]'
            AND 
              ( p.phone_number LIKE '%$search%'
             OR cu.company LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR CONCAT_WS(' ',cu.forename, cu.surname) LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR CONCAT_WS(' ',cu.second_forename, cu.second_surname) LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR CONCAT_WS(' ',cu.third_forename, cu.third_surname) LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR cu.email LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR cu.phone LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR cu.address1 LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR cu.address2 LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR cu.postcode LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR CONCAT_WS(' ',co.forename, co.surname) LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR co.email LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR co.phone LIKE '%$search%' 
             OR co.mobile LIKE '%$search%'
              )
          ORDER 
             BY cu.company ASC;
```

Comment: check my question, i have added the `$sql` output

Comment: my fault - i didnt see that. i have added `where company_status = 'Customer'` which returns rows but its only showing rows from the `customer` table where a row exists in `customer_phonelines` - basically what i am trying to do is search for information in 3 tables (customer, contacts and customer_phonelines) and display the results from the `customer` table

Comment: You select no columns from the phonelines table. So, I think you can remove that table from your query.

Comment: i need to be searching that table though. as i said "what i am trying to do is search for information in 3 tables (customer, contacts and customer_phonelines) and display the results from the customer table"

Comment: I fear we're heading in to philosphical territory. I suggest you try to reduce your problem to its simplest form and provide proper DDLs and a desired result accordingly.

Comment: i dont understand whats not simple. "what i am trying to do is search for information in 3 tables (customer, contacts and customer_phonelines) and display the results from the customer table"

Comment: If it's so simple, why are you asking us?

Comment: im sure thats obvious. look what i have tried and see i cannot get my query working which is why i have asked. you asked me to reduce my problem to its simplest form, if you dont feel you can help me then please do not waste your time and mine "trying" to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this by running this Query in PHP:

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT 
    customer.sequence, 
    customer.accountnumber, 
    customer.resellerid, 
    customer.voip_account, 
    customer.company, 
    customer.company_status, 
    customer.title, 
    customer.forename, 
    customer.surname, 
    customer.email, 
    customer.phone 

    FROM customer 
    INNER JOIN contacts ON customer.sequence = contacts.company 
    LEFT JOIN customer_phonelines ON customer.sequence = customer_phonelines.client_seq 

    WHERE ";

    if($_GET["type"] != '') {
        $sql.="customer.company_status = '".$_GET["type"]."' ";
    } else {
        $sql.="customer.company_status = 'Customer' ";
    }

    if($_GET["search"] != '') {
        $sql.="AND ";
        $sql.="(customer_phonelines.phone_number LIKE '%".$search."%' OR ";
        $sql.="customer.company LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        CONCAT_WS(' ',customer.forename, customer.surname) LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        CONCAT_WS(' ',customer.second_forename, customer.second_surname) LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        CONCAT_WS(' ',customer.third_forename, customer.third_surname) LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        customer.email LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        customer.phone LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        customer.address1 LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        customer.address2 LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        customer.postcode LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 

        CONCAT_WS(' ',contacts.forename, contacts.surname) LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        contacts.email LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        contacts.phone LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        contacts.mobile LIKE '%".$search."%') ";
    }
    $sql.="ORDER BY customer.company ASC ";
```

which works perfectly well